# Use Filter for NULL values on String type field

Tags: einstein-analytics

```
q = load "AnalyticsExtract";
q = filter q by 'IPM_Company__c' == "";
q = group q by 'all';
q = foreach q generate count() as 'count';
q = limit q 2000;
```

I want to filter the result with blank "`IPM_Company__c`" field. Here 'null' and not NULL operators are not working.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the is null after generate statement
for example

```
q = load "AnalyticsExtract";

q = foreach q generate 'IPM_Company__c' as 'IPM_Company__c';

q = filter q by 'IPM_Company__c' is null;

q = group q by 'all';

q = foreach q generate count() as 'count';

q = limit q 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Wave can be checked using empty string notation "".

```
q = load "AnalyticsExtract";
q = filter q by 'IPM_Company__c' == "";
```

Is that not working either? Checking a Text or a Picklist field value for empty value has always worked for me.
For example in one of my dashboards, the following line of code works perfectly:

```
q = filter q by 'OpportunityId.RecordTypeId.Name' != "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter statement only after a generate statement(projection). That is filter can be used on projection or post-projection not before projection.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

Instead of  using

> == and !=

operator for a string as these work for numeric data type instead use

> In and Not In

operator for string and check for null that will work 
your query can be like this

```
q = load "AnalyticsExtract";
q = filter q by 'IPM_Company__c' in [null];
q = group q by 'all';
q = foreach q generate count() as 'count';
q = limit q 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found.  field1 is a text field.

```
q = load "dataset";
q = for each q generate case when 'field1' is null then "" else 'field1' end
    as 'field1', 'field2' as 'field2';
q = filter q by 'field1' == "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `IPM_Company__c` is a Dimension you need to filter like this

```
q = filter q by IPM_Company__c =="";
```

is null   is only for measures not for dimensions.